# Работа с API. Обработка запроса выдает ошибку {"drivers":["This field is required."]}

Tags: php, api

Сразу хочу сказать, что я полный ноль в php, но решил изучать язык, чтобы решить свою прикладную задачу.
Итак, я хочу разобраться как работать с API сервиса agentapp. Иду последовательно, и запнулся на шаге объединение сущностей.
нужно передать ID нескольких элементов и получить на выходе ID заявки.
Выполняется этот код:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl6, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://widget.agentapp.ru/v1/insured_objects',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
        "drivers": [{
    '.$driver_id.'
  }],
    "owner": '.$owner_id.',
  "car": '.$car_id.'
 
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Authorization: Token '.$token.''
  ),
));

$response6 = curl_exec($curl6);

curl_close($curl6);
echo $response6;
```

И выдает ошибку:
{"drivers":["This field is required."]}

По этой ссылке выполняется код: https://one-click-polis.ru/api/

Специально проверил, что значения всех id присваиваются.
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вероятно в том, что json должен формироваться с помощью `json_encode()`  а не вот того, что у вас написано

Comment: Так как я новичок, то базу кода взял из документации: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/1182459/S1ZxcVkV?version=latest#9a9bbd77-0642-4233-bd04-1643686d0206 (выбрал язык php - curl) и пошел вставлять данные и смотреть, что отдает.